# Airflow run task if some of direct upstream are not triggered

Tags: airflow

I have a DAG, it has 5 tasks A,B,C,D,E. and 5 tasks triggered by failed tasks above, one for each, A_f, B_f, C_f, D_f and E_f (and similarly five on success). And at last, task X, which writes failure results to a database.
Lets say, if 2 of first five tasks failed (A and D), only A_f and D_f get triggered. What can I do to run task X? 
Will all_done work? even if some of the upstream tasks were never triggered? I am not so sure about it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes `all_done` should work. As long as none of Task X's upstream tasks have a state of `None`, which for any given dag run shouldn't be possible because tasks' states are inferred from previous tasks' states (i.e. skipped state is propagated or any children of a failed task are set to `upstream failed`), then the `all_done` trigger will work.